# How to differentiate between Scrolling by Mouse and scrolling done by dragging a window's scroll in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a functionality to implement based on scrolling.
Here is small snippet ::

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function(event)
{
  console.log(event.type);
  //Task to do
}
```

Here I want to differentiate that whether the binding is done by mouseScroll or by dragging a scroll.
By inspecting the event.type both are returning me "scroll" as event type.

Comment: what do you mean by dragging a scroll?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

Comment: Dragging means keeping the mouse Over scrollBar and then moving the page up and down.

Comment: You can consider to use a custom scrollbar plugin?

Comment: Using a custom scrollbar plugin is the last option in my mind.Is it not possible using windows scrollbar?

Comment: @RaviSingh:As Joews says you can use the mouseweel event or weel event i suggest also to see this page http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [wheel DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/wheel) to detect mousewheel events:

```
var isMouseScroll = false;

window.addEventListener('wheel',function(e)
{
  console.log('mouse wheel');
  isMouseScroll = true;
});

window.addEventListener('scroll',function(e)
{
  if(!isMouseScroll) {
    console.log('scroll');
  }

  isMouseScroll = false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/Cf666)

Note - don't confuse wheel with the deprecated, non-standard [mousewheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel) event.

Comment: +1 nice answer :) (I'd probably set isMouseScroll to false if it isn't mouse scroll but works either way)

Comment: Ah now I got it, sorry I was looking at it from the wrong direction, my bad^^

Comment: @joews : A small change in your answer has solved my problem. We need to stop the default action of scrolling while 'mouseWheel' event is triggered. I have added 'e.preventDefault()' in the binding function of wheel and it worked for me.

Comment: OK. That case is simpler because the `wheel` event won't have an accompanying `scroll` event, so you can remove the `isMouseScroll` check and `scroll` handler.

Comment: There is a note about support of `wheel` event here, looks like we need **IE9+** here.

Comment: however looks like you can check if `wheel` is supported first, then if not use `mousewheel` instead, it's a non-standard feature maybe because it's firstly introduced by IE, and it's supported by ***IE6***, maybe it runs OK from IE6 - IE8.