# Definitive quest to find if possible in Javascript to detect page scrolling by clicking on scroll bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a page that lets users scroll up and down via buttons I have created within the page.  It does this by jumping between anchor points in the page using the animate function within jQuery.

Now I have some functionality that I want to run ONLY when the page is manually scrolled by the web browser scroll bars.   To clarify, scrolling via mouse wheel or via my own buttons should be excluded from this logic.

Now I have a way to detect mouse wheel specific action that seems to work ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119269/how-to-differentiate-between-scrolling-by-mouse-and-scrolling-done-by-dragging-a))...

```
var isMouseScroll = false;

window.addEventListener('wheel',function(e){
  console.log('mouse wheel');
  isMouseScroll = true;
});

window.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
  if(!isMouseScroll) {
    console.log('scroll');
  }

  isMouseScroll = false;
});
```

but I don't know of a way to differentiate page content scrolling depending on if it was activated by a javascript piece of code or by the browsers own scrollbars.    The above code for example runs on either scrolling via code or if I manually drag the browsers scrollbars.   Does anyone have a better strategy to separate detection of these three different events ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
  // called when the window is scrolled.
}
```

If it doesn't differentiate with JavaScript initiated scrolling you may try to flag on the variable to detect if it is javascript initiated scrolling and execute the function code conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect, where event has been initiated. If you have:

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="content"></div></div>
```

styled f.e. as

```
#wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

than try this javascript:

```
function init () {
  document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
}

function mousedown (e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

You will see, that click on content will generate "content" and click on scrollbar will generate "wrapper".